# Formula for the characterisc function of a infinite intersections of sets.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let any characteristic function on set $S$ be denoted by $\mathcal{X}_S$. Note that if $E\cap F=A$ and $E\cup F=B$, then
$$
\mathcal{X}_A=\mathcal{X}_E\mathcal{X}_F\hskip 0.4cm \text{and}\hskip0.4cm
\mathcal{X}_B=\mathcal{X}_E+\mathcal{X}_F-\mathcal{X}_A.
$$
The question asks whether there are generalizations to finite and countably infinite intersections and unions. Using induction I was able to quickly show that countably infinite intersections can be generalized to.

However, I am struggling to find an appropriate (concise) formula for the unions. The difficulty is we can't just add on terms like we can for intersections, because that cause the $\mathcal{X}_B$ to exceed one. Any hints are appreciated!

This is a problem from Halmos's Measure Theory.

Comment: You could try something that uses the inclusion-exclusion principle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A=\bigcap_{E\in \mathcal{E}}E$, where $\mathcal{E}$ is an arbitrary collection of sets, then
$$
\chi_A=\chi_{\bigcap_{E\in \mathcal{E}}E}=\prod_{E\in \mathcal{E}}\chi_E.
$$
($x\in A \Leftrightarrow x\in E$ for all $E\in \mathcal{E} \Leftrightarrow \chi_{E}(x)=1$ for all $E\in \mathcal{E} \Leftrightarrow \chi_A(x)=1$). Consequently, if $B=\bigcup_{E\in \mathcal{E}}E$, then
$$
\chi_B=\chi_{\bigcup_{E\in \mathcal{E}}E}=1-\prod_{E\in \mathcal{E}}\chi_{E^c}=1-\prod_{E\in \mathcal{E}}(1-\chi_{E}).
$$

The inclusion-exclusion formula works for finite $\mathcal{E}$'s, i.e

$$
\chi_{B}=\sum_{J\subseteq\{1,\dots, n\}}(-1)^{|J|-1}\chi_{\cap_{i\in J}E_i}
$$

and does not necessarily extend to the infinite case.

Comment: Thank you! So your second centered equation does extend in the infinite case but not the third, right? In addition, would you mind add some details how to apply the inclusion-exclusion formula in this case?

Comment: @Kun Do you mean the proof of the inclusion-exclusion principle?

Comment: @d,k.o No, I mean how to apply it in the context. The inclusion-exclusion principle is a formula for calculating the cardinality of a set, but how does calculating a set's cardinality relate to the characteristic functions in question here?

Comment: @Kun Here is the proof using indicators:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Algebraic_proof